# How to debug Django app running on Heroku using a remote pdb connection?

Tags: python, django, debugging, heroku, pdb

To debug a bug I'm seeing on Heroku but not on my local machine, I'm trying to do step-through debugging.

The typical `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` approach doesn't work with Heroku since you don't have access to a console connected to your app, but apparently you can use [rpdb](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/rpdb/), a "remote" version of pdb.

So I've installed rpdb, added `import rpdb; rpdb.set_trace()` at the appropriate spot. When I make a request that hits the rpdb line, the app hangs as expected and I see the following in my heroku log:

```
pdb is running on 3d0c9fdd-c18a-4cc2-8466-da6671a72cbc:4444
```

Ok, so how to connect to the pdb that is running? I've tried `heroku run nc 3d0c9fdd-c18a-4cc2-8466-da6671a72cbc 4444` to try to connect to the named host from within heroku's system, but that just immediately exits with status 1 and no error message.

So my specific question is: how do I now connect to this remote pdb?

The general related question is: is this even the right way for this sort of interactive debugging of an app running on Heroku? Is there a better way?

NOTE RE CELERY: Note, I've now also tried a similar approach with Celery, to no avail. The default host celery's rdb (remote pdb wrapper) uses is `localhost`, which you can't get to when it's Heroku. I've tried using the `CELERY_RDB_HOST` environment variable to the domain of the website that is being hosted on Heroku, but that gives a "Cannot assign requested address" error. So it's the same basic issue -- how to connect to the remote pdb instance that's running on Heroku?

Answer (score 3):

In answer to your second question, I do it differently depending on the type of error (browser-side, backend, or view).  For backend and view testing (unittests), will something like this work for you?

```
$ heroku run --app=your-app "python manage.py shell --settings=settings.production"
```

Then debug-away within ipython:

```
>>> %run -d script_to_run_unittests.py
```

Even if you aren't running a django app you could just run the debugger as a command line option to ipython so that any python errors will drop you to the debugger:

```
$ heroku run --app=your-app "ipython --pdb"
```

Front-end testing is a whole different ballgame where you should look into tools like selenium. I think there's also a "salad" test suite module that makes front end tests easier to write. Writing a test that breaks is the first step in debugging (or so I'm told ;).

If the bug looks simple, you can always do the old "print and run" with something like

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__file__)
logger.warn('here be bugs')`
```

and review your log files with getsentry.com or an equivalent monitoring tool or just:

```
heroku logs --tail
```

Comment: Good stuff but not sure how these approaches help you debug a response to a server request? (To be specific, my bug is in a template tag which is behaving strange on Heroku compared to locally.)

Comment: @Ghopper21 you could log the server request response or run the debugger (set a breakpoint with `import ipdb;ipdb.set_trace()`) where the server response has been composed (in your view) so you can examine it.