# How to trace code in a Heroku production system

Tags: python, django, heroku, pycharm, trace

My Python/Django code behaves different in the heroku production code, than on my development machine.

I would like to debug/trace it.

Since it runs on Heroku. AFAIK I can't insert `import pydevd_pycharm;  pydevd_pycharm.settrace(...` into the code.

I use PyCharm.

But I don't need a fancy GUI. A command-line tool would be fine, too.

I would be happy if I could see all lines which get executed during a particular http request.

How to solve this for production systems?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to debug Django app running on Heroku using a remote pdb connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15801835/how-to-debug-django-app-running-on-heroku-using-a-remote-pdb-connection)

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat not really: "...app hangs as expected" I don't want the production system to hang :-)

Comment: Did you try PUDB? (https://pypi.org/project/pudb/) Not sure if can be used on Heroku: do you have an SSH connection available?

Comment: @MarioOrlandi thank you for the link do pudb. It looks like a nice tool.

Comment: Try using django debug toolbar

Comment: @ReshabDas I know the debug toolbar. But AFAIK the debug-toolbar has no tracing up to now. It would be great if it had one.

Comment: You also have django-trace but for dev environment only. Generally code trace is done in dev environment only. Doing it in production environment is not heard of

Comment: @ReshabDas have you ever used "django-trace"?

Comment: @guettli yes i did but only in development using `python manage.py trace runserver`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to understand the difference between your local development environment and the Heroku production I would **first** deploy the application on another Heroku Dyno, for example **a Free Dyno** which you can easily create and manage.
You can then integrate the tools you want and add the log statements as needed.

Even if you are able to debug/inspect the production runtime it is very important to be able to test on production-like systems to capture problems early and investigate problems without guessing.

On the Prod system you have limited options to debug the application:

- consider **code changes** (i.e. add logging stamements) but as you have pointed out this involves PRs and a new release
- **debugger**: connect your favourite debugger (i.e. PyCharm) to the remote application. This is something that (almost) no one does (given the security aspects and the likely impact on the application performance) and I doubt your system admins/DevOps would agree

Comment: I would totally recommand the staging environment pipeline with the same code, just a different logging options (level=debug)!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any tool which can do that, but you shouldn't run into this problem very often. So I wouldn't bother trying to solve this generally, but instead just add logging statements where you think they can be handy to debug this one problem.

Comment: I can't add logging statements to code which runs in the production. I could, but it would need days and several PR-reviews to get there.